# Retrieve country name using country code in app language not phone locale language

Tags: swift, localization, locale, country-codes

I'm using `Localize_Swift` library. I change the app language using it. Now I'm retrieving country name using country code using this.

```
class Country: NSObject {

   class func locale(for countryCode : String) -> String {
    
       let identifier = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: countryCode)
       let countryName = identifier.displayName(forKey: NSLocale.Key.countryCode, value: countryCode)
    
       return countryName?.uppercased() ?? ""
   
   }
}
```

The function is returning the country name in the phone locale language and not the app language. Is there a way to make it return the country name in the its locale language name.

> Example: Germany -> Deutschland

> Example: Austria -> Österreich

Or any suggestions for a work around?

Comment: I copy/pasted your code and `Country.locale(for: "eg")` returned `Egypt` (I have no "Egypt" in any of my local language settings), and `print(Country.locale(for: "il"))` returned `Israel`, although I have no Israel in my local settings either. So you have to provide a more specific issue that fails

Comment: @KirilS. You don't need to have them installed in you phone. But they are available country codes that you can retrieve in the code using `NSLocale`. What I need is to retrieve the country name in it local language name. For example Germany to be Deutschland.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to specify the language when initializing your Locale:

```
struct Country {
    static func locale(for regionCode: String, language: String = "en") -> String? {
        Locale(identifier: language + "_" + regionCode)
            .localizedString(forRegionCode: regionCode)
   }
}
```

---

```
Country.locale(for: "DE")                  // "Germany"
Country.locale(for: "DE", language: "de")  // "Deutschland"
```

If you would like to automatically select the language based on the country/region code:

```
struct Country {
    static func locale(for regionCode: String) -> String? {
        let languageCode = Locale(identifier: regionCode).languageCode ?? "en"
        return Locale(identifier: languageCode + "_" + regionCode)
            .localizedString(forRegionCode: regionCode)
   }
}
```

---

```
Country.locale(for: "DE")   // "Deutschland"
```

Answer (score 0):

Leaving this here for those using iOS16+. You can now make use of 'Locale' like so:

```
Locale.current.localizedString(forRegionCode: "fr")
```

... which will then output:

```
Optional("France")
```

Or altenatively, you could do the following to get an array with all country names:

```
Locale.Region.isoRegions.compactMap { Locale.current.localizedString(forRegionCode: $0.identifier) }
```

Comment: Your first example has been valid since iOS 8.0, not iOS 16. It's only your second example that requires iOS 16. Also note that the list of `isoRegions` is not just a list of countries, it is a list of regions.